# Use Alomofire for get data from server in Xcode 9

Tags: json, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I'm beginner in iOS programming but I work in android so now I stuck in a problem in iOS.
I know my question is general but I really need your help!
in android for connect to server we do like below:

```
 Call<String> myList = service.Contact_List("");
        myList.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                try{
                    ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body());

                    for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++)
                        contactArrayList.add(gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Contact.class));

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Catch","Error")
                }finally {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Failure","Error")
            }
        });
```

and in xcode I do like below :

```
let url = URL(string: "http://api.example.com/Contact-List")
Alamofire.request(url!, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: param, encoding:  URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
   print("response.request")
  print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
   print("response.response")
    print(response.response as Any) // URL response
    print("response.result.value") 
}
```

and my result is something like this:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Mary","TelNumber":"09111111"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Sarah","TelNumber":"09222222"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"Ben","TelNumber":"09333333"}]
```

now my question is that how can I do like this code in Xcode(swift 3 ):

```
for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length() ; i++)
                            contactArrayList.add(gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Contact.class));
```

in addition, I use ASP.net in server side.

I am really sorry about my long and ambiguous question!
thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create NSObject swift file :

then add code

```
class demo {

var ID: String
var Name: String


init(ID: String, Name: String) {
    self.ID = ID
    self.Name = Name

}
}
```

Try like this way :

```
let data = response.result.value
            if data != nil {
                self.presentWindow.hideToastActivity()
                if let response = data as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for detail_data in response {
                        let Id = detail_data["Id"] as? String ?? ""
                        let Name = detail_data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let demoObj = demo(ID: ID, Name: Name
                        self.demoObjects.append(demoObj)
                    } 
                }
             }
```

**Updated Answer**

for converting string response to JSON

Sample code will be something like this. Don't forget to handle unwrap stuff

```
let data1 = "[{\"Id\": 1,\"Name\": \"Mary\",\"TelNumber\": \"09111111\"},{\"Id\": 2,\"Name\": \"Sarah\",\"TelNumber\": \"09222222\"}]" //your JSON From API Response
    let data = data1.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String : Any]]
                for detail_data in array {
                    let Id = detail_data["Id"] as? Int ?? 00
                    let Name = detail_data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                    print("Id:",Id)
                    print("Name:",Name)
                    print("****")
                }


        } catch {
            print("Exception occured \(error))")
        }
```

Comment: what is cartItem?! I mean when does it fill that now is used?

Comment: @Mahya i m not getting you can u please explain in detail?

Comment: I mean , when data cast to [[String: AnyObject]] , result is nil so if statement is nil and doesn't do rest of code!

Comment: try to print(response) and let me know what you get ?

Comment: this is response: [{"Id":1,"Name":"Mary","TelNumber":"09111111"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Sarah","TelNumber":"09222222"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"Ben","TelNumber":"09333333"}] I think my problem is that response's type is String, I'm not sure I just guess!

Comment: excuse me! I make a mistake ,response is nil but this is data :[{"Id":1,"Name":"Mary","TelNumber":"09111111"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Sarah","TelNumber":"09222222"}, {"Id":3,"Name":"Ben","TelNumber":"09333333"}]

Comment: @Mahya it was working fine with me just now i tested

Comment: can u please change 
Alamofire.request(url!, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: param, encoding:  URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

encoding to JSONEncoding.default instead of URLEncoding.default

Comment: I did it before but the result was empty! I mean when I print response.result.value, result is []!! really thanks for your help

Comment: @Mahya than you have to convert string response to JSON than you can go through loop .if you are not getting feel free to ask .I am here to help you.